# XSLT complex sorting and grouping

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xsl-grouping

I have an XML file looked like this:

```
<components>
       <comp>
      <ref>q7</ref>
      <partnumber>foo</partnumber>
   </comp>
   <comp>
      <ref>q1</ref>
      <partnumber>foo</partnumber>
   </comp>
   <comp>
      <ref>q6</ref>
      <partnumber>bar</partnumber>
   </comp>
   <comp>
      <ref>q3</ref>
      <partnumber>bar</partnumber>
   </comp>
</components>
```

And I need to goup by partnumber and sort by ref, so that output file will look like this:

```
q1 q7, foo
q3 q6, bar
```

But I'm getting this output:

```
q3 q6, bar
q1 q7, foo
```

Here is my XSL:

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
  <!ENTITY nl  "&#xd;&#xa;">    <!--new line CR, LF, or LF, your choice -->
]>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:key name='compspec' match="comp" use="partnumber" />
    <xsl:template match="/components">
        <xsl:for-each select="comp[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('compspec',partnumber)[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="ref"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('compspec',partnumber)">
                <xsl:sort select="ref"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="ref"/>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="partnumber"/>
            <xsl:text>&nl;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I understand why I'm getting this sequence, but I'm pretty new for XSLT and i don't know how to fix it. Whate should I fix in my code? I'm using XSLT 1.0. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to sort groups with equal part number by minimum value of
>   comp/ref

To do this in XSLT 1.0, you will have to make two passes:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name='compspec' match="comp" use="partnumber" />

<xsl:template match="/components">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="groups">
        <xsl:for-each select="comp[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('compspec',partnumber)[1])]">
            <group name="{partnumber}">
                <xsl:for-each select="key('compspec', partnumber)">
                    <xsl:sort select="ref"/>
                    <value>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ref"/>
                    </value>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($groups)/group">
        <xsl:sort select="value[1]"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note**:
In your example, `ref` contains text values and in the code above it is sorted *as text*. Therefore, *minimum value of comp/ref* is actually *the first `ref` value in alphabetical order*.

Comment: Is there a solution without using exsl?

Comment: Maybe.  Why are you asking? Doesn't your processor support `exsl:node-set()`? Practically all of them do.

Comment: Just very interesting how it should be done without using exsl

Comment: I suppose the next best alternative would be to make two **real** passes - i..e. use two XSLT files and an interim XML file. Otherwise it would get really ugly and slow (and I am afraid I don't find it interesting at all).

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the desired output if you just delete this line:

```
 <xsl:sort select="partnumber"/>
```

in your first `for-each` loop, because you're sorting alphabetically by  `partnumber` (`bar` and `foo`).

Comment: I don't need to sort by partnumber, i need to sort  groups by minimum value of ref

Comment: I edited my code in question. Now it sorts groups with equal partnumber by first occurrence  in xml comp/ref with desired partnumber. I need to sort groups with equal part number by minimum value of comp/ref with desired partnumber